# Reading and updating array of reference type in Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore in flutter. I have a field in document that is an array of **reference** type. I want to read it and further want to add new values to this array but I am not sure how to do it though I am able read the reference type element value as a string. I am stuck here. Can anyone guide me how to do it. Below is the code with the screenshots of structure and data.

```
DocumentReference docRef = docRef = widget.function.variants;
```

[image: Data in Firestore doc as reference type array]

[image: Values received in code]

Comment: Are you asking [how to read a document from Firestore inn Flutter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#dart_2)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen No, I want to read this array which is of type DocumentReference along with this I want to add new values to this as well.

Comment: Do you want to do both operations (read and write) in a single go?

Comment: @AlexMamo No, separately.

Comment: Ok, then show us what you have tried and what exactly doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: @AlexMamo I did with the help of your medium article by using "FieldValue.arrayUnion".

Comment: @SalmanAkbar Good to hear that, Salman.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a map of document references, and you want to append to that map,
you'll need to:

1. Create the relevant doc in Firestore (if not yet created)
2. Get the reference to that doc (using firebase *doc()* function) -
   of type *DocumentReference*
3. Add that reference to your map
4. Save back to Firestore.

Although you are able to cast these values to string, they are actually references to other documents in your Firestore DB. new values, should be added as such.